# How to organize files in Linux/Unix shell?

Tags: shell, command-line, files, cygwin

I would like to try to organize my documents, and I was told that I can do this using the linux/unix cygwin terminal. I searched for the command in google but all I ever did find was organizing the data on the file itself.

What I would like to do is organize all .docx files and place it into a folder, same goes with other file type like .txt, .sh, etc. which should be place in a different folder...

Any ideas on how should I go with doing that?

Comment: Did you try to do this yourself or you are expecting someone to tell you how to do it ?

Comment: Do you have experiance using the terminal? Can you list files in it, or rather where are the files that you want to sort (are they in one or in different folders)? Did you already create these directories where you want to put the files?

Comment: There are plenty of good tutorials online. [Something like this](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-move-files-using-linux-commands-or-file-managers) would be a good place to start - the command line section.

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple commands such as cp/mv to the directory you want.

For example:

In the directory where your files are located

```
mkdir wordDocs
mv *docx wordDocs/
```